# How to mock sql update in go

Tags: postgresql, go

I'm trying to write a unit test for updating record in postgresql in golang

database function is

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test.update(param_id text, param_data jsonb, id2 text) RETURNS void AS
$$
BEGIN
    UPDATE test.test_table
    SET data = param_data,
    WHERE id = (SELECT id FROM test.test_table2 WHERE name = id2)
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Unit test is

```
rows := sqlmock.NewRows([]string{"result"}).AddRow("")

mock.ExpectBegin()
mock.ExpectQuery(fmt.Sprintf("SELECT %v.update(.+)", schema)).WithArgs(1, data).WillReturnRows(rows)
mock.ExpectCommit()
```

Do I also need to mock the select query inside?  How can I mock a void function?

Comment: Your best bet for unit testing Postgres stored procedures is to use [pgTAP](http://pgtap.org/).

Answer (score 0):

I've used the following package

> import (sql "database/sql")

this enables me to check the following,

`....
var rows sql.Result
...
<execute query >
... 
rows.RowsAffected()`

rows.RowsAffected() provides the number of rows updated.